# Vimeo api authentication into rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, vimeo

Vimeo writing Making Requests

After you have either an authenticated or unauthenticated access token (as explained in the preceding sections), send the access token through the authorization header:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <OAUTH_TOKEN>" https://api.vimeo.com
```

and it's work, but in my application I can't be authorized

```
RestClient.post 'https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client', {grant_type: 'client_credentials', client_id: Rails.application.secrets.vimeo_id, client_secret: Rails.application.secrets.vimeo_secret}
```

> RestClient::Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized

Please somebody tell me how I can do authenticated to success...

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned different requests.
To get an access toket with RestClient do:

```
r = RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post, 
                            url: "https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client",
                            payload: {grant_type: "client_credentials"},
                            user: VIMEO_CLIENT_ID,
                            password: VIMEO_CLIENT_SECRET)
=> "{\"access_token\":\"scrt12334\",\"token_type\":\"bearer\",\"scope\":\"public\",\"app\":{\"name\":\"test\",\"uri\":\"/apps/79881\"}}"

token = JSON.parse(r)['access_token']
=> "scrt12334"
```

And then get an API endpoints with Bearer authorization:

```
methods = RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: "https://api.vimeo.com", payload: {}, headers: {"Authorization"=>"Bearer #{token}"})

=> "{\"endpoints\":[{\"path\":\"https://api.vimeo.com/\",\"methods\":[\"GET\",\"OPTIONS\"]},....
```